# Rails 5: AssociationTypeMismatch error when creating Payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `Payment` and `Coupon` controller.
`Payment` has_one `Coupon`, and `Coupon` belongs_to `Payment`.
My Payment form have an `text_field :Coupon` to add it to `payment`. When `Payment` being created, i got the error said **ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in PaymentsController#create**. I have searched this error before, the solution is add `nested_form` to `Payment`. But i think it will wrong. Because i dont want create new `coupon` while creating `payment`, i just want add existing `Coupon` to `Payment`
How can i resolve this? Swap association between `Payment` and `Coupon`? `Payment` belongs_to `Coupon`, and `Coupon` has_one `Payment`?

Update: 
I delete `has_one coupon`, and  add `voucher(string)` column to payment model. This error is not show anymore. I cant understand. Can anyone explain the reason to me?

Comment: I fear that `coupon has_many payment` will make chance to hacked easier

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in PaymentsController#create` because Rails is expecting you to pass in a Coupon object and you are not.

To achieve what you want to do you will need to either use a nested form as you mentioned or either seed or create Coupons into the database.

Then in your form have a dropdown of coupons where a user can select which one they want to apply.

Comment: I have coupon model too. Coupon is not given for every user, so i  cant change text input to dropdown